# Trigger dataTables column visibilty change only on user interaction

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am using DataTables 1.13.2.

Whenever the user changes the column visibility, we store the information (so later we can open the datatable with the stored column visibility). We use the following event to achieve this:

```
$('#tblCustomers').on('column-visibility.dt', function (e, settings, column, state) {
    saveVisibleColumns('tblCustomers');
});
```

This works fine. But when we destroy and recreate the table (due to some changes, we need to do this), the above event is triggered for each and every column of the table. More precisely, the event is triggered for each column on table destroy. I would like the above function to be called only when the user manually changes the column visibility and not when the table is destroyed.

The whole code looks something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  buildTable();

  $('#tblCustomers').on('column-visibility.dt', function (e, settings, column, state) {
    saveVisibleColumns('tblCustomers');
  });
}

function buildTable() {
  if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#tblCustomers')) {
    $('#tblCustomers').DataTable().destroy();
  }

  $('#tblCustomers').createGrid(...);
}

function whenTableNeedsToBeRebuilt() {
  ...
  buildTable();
}
```